# How do I make a change in Wordpress nav-menus.php file permanent without editing it directly?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to comment out/remove line 387 in the latest WP 3.6.1:

```
$args['menu-item-xfn'] = implode( ' ', array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', explode( ' ', $args['menu-item-xfn'] ) ) );
```

and is there any way I can do that via a custom functions.php file or something? Just so I am not editing the core file every time a WP update happens?

I need to stop the WP from sanitizing the XFN Link Relationship value from the Nav Menus... and leave it as entered.

Thanks!

Comment: Check [Walker_Nav_Menu](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output/).

Comment: I am looking at it... but can't figure out how to edit the wp_update_nav_menu_item() function in wp-includes/nav-menus.php to exclude that line 387 from the code. Do I copy the whole function the same way as in that example you posted?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and jQuery helps!
just add a class to the menu item (make sure to activate classes in the screen options) and add use the following code:

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.your_class a').attr('rel', 'shadowbox;width=405;height=340;')
});`